Python data visualization for x and y axis numerical data
I have list of numbers in my x and y axis (not in ordered). There are few numbers which have some relation. The weightage of that relation is given as number in z axis.
I want to represent these x and y axis as bar diagrams (parallelly) with numbers on it. The relation i want to represent as lines of varies thickness (depends on higher values in z axis). How to do it using python?


Can you do it in Excel? Your description is a little vague, if you can show what you're after (the Graph layout in Excel ) as an image others can better understand what Python code would need to be implemented. However note this is not a code writing site. You are expected to have tried to do this (in Python) yourself and include the attempt (code) in the Post, asking questions related to that if you had problems. Your Post will likely be closed for this reason.
